# How to get list from controller to view when view is already attached to an Entity Framework table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to get list select list data from controller to view as I have a list in controller like:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> Survey()
{
    // List<string> QuestionType = new List<string> { "SingleLineTextBox", "MultiLineTextBox", "YesOrNo", "SingleSelect", "MultiSelect" };
    List<SelectListItem> QuestionType = new List<SelectListItem>()
               {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "SingleLineTextBox",  
                                           Value = "SingleLineTextBox"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "MultiLineTextBox", 
                                           Value = "MultiLineTextBox"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "YesOrNo", Value = "YesOrNo" },
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "SingleSelect", Value = "SingleSelect"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "MultiSelect", Value = "MultiSelect"}
               };
    return QuestionType;
}
```

I have written my view as under I have a dropdown in view in which i want to add this list item,

```
@model Survey.Question

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageQuestion";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend> Enter Questions For Survey</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Question Type")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownFor("QuestionType")

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Title");
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Text)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Description")
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Value")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(a=>a.Options)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

`@Html.DropDownFor("QuestionType")` is a dropdown in which I want to add list items; `Survey.Question` is table `Question` in database `Survey`. I can write it like this to get list item in view but I have added table in model as I need data from table:

```
@model List<SelectListItem>
```

How can I figure it out in order to get list from controller to view?

Hoping for your suggestion

Comment: you need a query to attach your database table data to selectlistitem list

Comment: @john Possibly create new ViewModel & it has object of table [Question] & List of Question Types & send ViewModel to view. So you can access both object & list in view. User List to populate your Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways around this one being said b D-Shih as you send the list via a ViewBag/ViewData and such but i prefer you send it via a ViewModel.

So Question Model is what you have bound to the view. you can easily add the following properties to your model:

```
Public Class Question
{
   //Other Properties
   public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

While you are filling the `Items` within the Question Model you may later want to take the `SelectedItemId` so you add it there as well (my suggestion is that you create a ViewModel for this one).

Then in your controller:

```
Question q = new Question();
q.Items = Survey(); //this is your method that returns SelectListItem, or you can create it here.
return view(q);
```

Then Within your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId , Model.Items , "-- Select Type --")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have little success in getting one method for getting list on view from controller that is,

I returned the list from view like,

```
   List<SelectListItem> QuestionType = Survey();
            return View(QuestionType);
```

Use tuple to add more than one value to model ,

```
@model Tuple<Survey.Question,List<SelectListItem>>
```

Get the value for textbox from it like,

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>Model.Item1.Options)
```

But getting type error while getting value for dropdown,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor("QuestionType", Model.Item2)
```

Hopefully some syntax error any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> QuestionType = new List<SelectListItem>();
    QuestionType.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "SingleLineTextBox",
             Value = "SingleLineTextBox"
         });
    QuestionType.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "MultiLineTextBox",
             Value = "MultiLineTextBox",
             Selected = true
         });
    QuestionType.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "YesOrNo",
             Value = "YesOrNo"
         });
             QuestionType.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "SingleSelect",
             Value = "SingleSelect"
         });
             QuestionType.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "MultiSelect",
             Value = "MultiSelect"
         });
}

@Html.DropDownList("DDlDemo", new SelectList(QuestionType, "Value", "Text"))
```